# New VBAproject open prevention

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel report that has VBA code written.When i try to view code, alongwith my code that is under display a new project VBAproject(Book 1) opens.Using this new workbook code can be written that changes my values in excel.I cannot set Userinterfaceonly to false as this doesnt allow the internal VBA to run.

Can the VBAproject(book 1) that opens alongwith my code under display be prevented/locked so that no new code can be written?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a password on VBA associated with a workbook.

Open the VBA editor for the workbook you want to protect. Select the project, and go to the Tools Menu, then the VBAProject Properties option. Clicki the Protection tab, and set the password, confirm it, click OK. Save the workbook.

Now if you try to open the VBA for that workbook you'll be prompted for the password, but the VBA can still be called.

PS Don't forget the password!